# Can be template function within class template specialized outside of the class template?

Tags: c++, templates

Can be template function within class template specialized outside of the class template?
What is the syntax for it?

Following code gives `unable to match function definition to an existing declaration` in MSVC2010

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    template <typename S>
    void test(const S & t);

    //this works
    //template<> void test(const double & t) { std::cout << t << "D \n"; }

    T member;
};

//this doesn't work
template <typename T>
template <>
void Test<T>::test(const double & t)
{
    std::cout << t << "D \n";
}

int main()
{
    Test<int> t;
    t.test(7.0);
}
```

**edit**

I can use overload as suggested in answers, because I use it little differently, here is how:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    template <typename S>
    void test() { std::cout << "Any type \n"; }

    template <>
    void test<double>() { std::cout << "Double! \n"; }

    T member;
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t1;
    Test<int> t2;
    t1.test<float>();
    t2.test<double>();
}
```

and I want specialization for double outside of the `struct`.

Why I use it like this you ask? In real scenario I have built factory class which is used like:

```
Factory<SomePolicy> f;
f.create<MyType>(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

and I need specialization of `create` for specific type which won't pollute header file.

Comment: Empty `template <>` can not follow non-empty `template <typename S>`. So you can only write something like this: `template <> template <typename S> void Test<double>::test(const S & t){/*...*/}` which is of course not what you want. And you can't declare or define specializations inside a class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can specialize the inner template without specializing the outer. You could, however, use partial specialization:

Edit: It appears that only classes can be partially specialized. Again, I haven't tested it. You can find more [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)

```
template <typename T, typename S>
struct Test 
{
   void test(const S &s);
};

template <typename T>
struct Test<T, float>
{
   void test (const float &s)
   {
      <<do something>>
   }
}
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to use `struct` instead of `class` in example code. Otherwise you have to explicitly mark some things `public`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think it no good. 1) this is uncompilable, 2) there is big difference between class template with 2 template arguments and class template with one argument and template member function

Comment: @Brian that's exactly why I used struct

Comment: I did say I hadn't run the code. Also, it's partially wrong. Editing now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't. But you can just overload your `test` function like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    template <typename S>
    void test(const S & t);

    void test(const double &); // <-- Add this

    T member;
};

template <typename T> 
// template<> // <-- Remove this
void Test<T>::test(const double & t)
{
    std::cout << t << "D \n";
}
```

Which should be totally equivalent to what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, this won't work in my case. Please, see edit of my question.